# Simple way to load specific sample using Pytorch dataloader

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am currently training a 3D CNN for binary classification with relatively sparse labels (~ 1% of voxels in label data correspond to target class).

In order to perform basic sanity checks during the training (e.g. does the network learn at all?) it would be handy to present the network with a small, handpicked subset of training examples having an above-average fraction of target class labels.

As suggested by the Pytorch documentation, I implemented my own `dataset` class (inheriting from `torch.utils.data.Dataset`) which provides training examples via it's `__get_item__` method to the `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.

In the [pytorch tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) I found, the `DataLoader` is used as an iterator to generate the training loop like so:

```
for i, data in enumerate(self.dataloader):

    # Get training data
    inputs, labels = data

    # Train the network
    # [...]
```

**What I am wondering now is whether there exist a simple way to load a single or a couple of specific training examples** (using a the linear index understood by `Dataset`'s `__get_item__` method). However, `DataLoader` does not have a `__get_item__` method and repeatedly calling `__next__` until I reach the desired index does not seem elegant.

Apparently one possible way to solve this would be to define a custom `sampler` or `batch_sampler` inheriting from the abstract `torch.utils.data.Sampler`. But this seems over the top to retrieve a few specific samples.

I suppose I am overlooking something very simple and obvious here. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case anyone with a similar question comes across this at some point:

The quick-and-dirty workaround I ended up using was to bypass the `dataloader` in the training loop by directly accessing it's associated `dataset` attribute. Suppose we want to quickly check if our network learns at all by repeatedly presenting it a single, handpicked training example with linear index `sample_idx` (as defined by the dataset class).

Then one can do something like this:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(self.dataloader):

    # Get training data
    # inputs, labels = data

    inputs, labels = self.dataloader.dataset[sample_idx]
    inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(0)
    labels = labels.unsqueeze(0)

    # Train the network
    # [...]
```

EDIT:

One brief remark, since some people seem to be finding this workaround helpful: When using this hack I found it to be crucial to instantiate the `DataLoader` with `num_workers = 0`. Otherwise, memory segmentation errors might occur in which case you could end up with very weird looking training data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined

```
train_set = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='~/datasets/', train=True,
                                                download=True, transform=(transform['train']))
```

then you can do something like

`train_set.data[index]` where `index` is the `index` of the specific example you want.

Now you can redefine you `Dataset` class with this new dataset that includes these specific examples and there you have it.

Comment: Your suggestion is equivalent to accessing `dataloader.dataset[sample_idx]`, since the `dataloader` object contains the `dataset` object as an attribute.